# UnboundLocalError for variable imported from settings.py

Tags: python

I have a file settings.py which has the following variables defined:

```
DEBUG_MODE = True
WRAP_UP = False
```

I am importing settings into my script using:

```
from settings import *
```

I am able to run this without any problem:

```
if(DEBUG_MODE):
    # Do something
```

But when I run this:

```
if(WRAP_UP == False):
    # Do something
```

it gives me the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'WRAP_UP' referenced before assignment.
```

Why does one variable work and the other doesn't? How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you attempt to assign to `WRAP_UP`? If so, that won't work. `import *` doesn't work that way.

Comment: The error says you should run 'WRAP_UP=something' before using it, is there a situation that 'WRAP_UP = False' does not run ?

Comment: Are you by any chance doing this `import` in the middle of a function?

Comment: If not, are you assigning to `WRAP_UP` in some other function, and forgetting the `global WRAP_UP`?

Comment: Also, is this Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: yes, the problem is that i am stating WRAP_UP = True somewhere in the program. Problem solved.

Comment: @user2353418: Actually, `import *` does work that way, at least at the global level. (Inside a function, it's a huge mess… which is why it generates warnings in 2.7 and is a syntax error in 3.x. So hopefully that's not the issue.)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, inside a function, any variables you don't explicitly declare `global` or `nonlocal` (closure) are considered local if you assign to them anywhere in the function, non-local (closure, global, or builtin) if you don't.

So, assuming you do the `from settings import *` globally (if not, you have bigger problems…), that creates global variables named `DEBUG_MODE` and `WRAP_UP`, so you can do this:

```
def spam():
    if DEBUG_MODE:
        # Do something
```

… and that works. But if you do this:

```
def eggs():
    if WRAP_UP:
        # Do something
    WRAP_UP = True
```

… that won't work. The assignment means that `eggs` has a local variable named `WRAP_UP`, which hides the global variable of the same name. So, the first line is trying to access that local variable, which doesn't have a value yet.

The solution is an explicit `global` statement, which will force `eggs` to use the global variable even though it has an assignment:

```
def eggs():
    global WRAP_UP
    if WRAP_UP:
        # Do something
    WRAP_UP = True
```

Of course that's assuming that you *want* `eggs` to reassign the global, but I suspect that's what you want.

Comment: This will change `WRAP_UP` in this module, but not other modules. Intuitively, we might expect `import *` to share the imported module's variables across all modules that import it.

Comment: @user2357112: That's true, but hopefully the OP understands enough about globals vs. builtins in Python that he knows what he's doing, or is willing to learn. We _could_ change things to push the imported variables into builtins or something to try to hide the problem instead of letting him address it if it comes up, but I don't think that's a good idea.